# Node.js, Mongodb: How to use `promise.then` to set a global variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In the code there is a `promise.then` that is attempted to be used to set a global variable `originalUrl`, however `originalUrl` is not being changed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

myApp.js:

```
// create a mongoose model
var urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  original_url: String,
  short_url: String
});
urlSchema.plugin(findOrCreate)
var Url = mongoose.model('Url', urlSchema);

let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  app.post("/api/shorturl/new", (req, res) => {
    // receive an url in the post and return a
    // short id. After that, the short id can be used
    // to go to the original url.
    // Handle the data in the POST request
    // get the hostname from the request
    
    originalUrl = req.body.url;
    // Create an identifier for the url
    shortUrl = md5(originalUrl).toString().slice(-7) 
    
     // test to see if the host is live
    var url = new URL(originalUrl);
    hostname = url.hostname;

    // if host is live
    dns.lookup(hostname, function (err) {
      if (err == undefined){
        // if not found, save the original_url and the 
        // short_url, return
          Url.findOrCreate({ original_url: originalUrl, short_url: shortUrl}, (err, result) => {
          console.log(result)

          res.json({
          original_url: originalUrl,
          short_url: shortUrl
          }); 
        })
      }

      if (err != undefined){
        console.log(">>> error <<<")
        res.json({"error":"host down"});
      }
    });
    resolve(originalUrl)
  });
})
promise.then(
  function(result) { originalUrl = result },
  function(error) { /* handle an error */ }
);

console.log(originalUrl) // undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the function passed to `then()` isn't run until the promise resolves. So instead of this:

```
promise.then(
  function(result) { originalUrl = result },
  function(error) { /* handle an error */ }
);

console.log(originalUrl)
```

...you need to do something more like this:

```
promise.then(
  function(result) { originalUrl = result },
  function(error) { /* handle an error */ }
).then(
  function() { console.log(originalUrl); }
);
```

Here's a simple runnable sample that hopefully gives an idea as to how this works:

```js
var originalUrl = undefined;

var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout( function() {
    resolve("http://example.com");
  }, 250) 
});

promise.then(
  function(result) { originalUrl = result },
  function(error) { /* handle an error */ }
).then(
  function() { console.log('promise resolved: ', originalUrl); }
);
console.log('promise pending: ', originalUrl);
```

The results:

```
promise pending:  undefined
promise resolved:  http://example.com
```